# Bootstrap Tags Input - values doesn't get removed from tagsinput

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

I am trying to remove input value from `bootstrap-tags-input` manually  whenever `x` button is clicked but values doesn't gets change nor from *array* neither from *inputs* .

This is **code** which i have tried :

```js
$('input').tagsinput({
  allowDuplicates: true
});
//on click of remove button
$(document).on("click", ".label-info span[data-role=remove]", function() {
  //remove that spn
  var to_remove = $(this).closest(".label-info").clone().children().remove().end().text().trim()
  console.log($("[name=tags]").val())
  //if i put here inisde split `,` not working as well
  var values = $("[name=tags]").val().split(';')
  console.log("to remove ---" + to_remove)
  $(this).closest(".label-info").remove()
  console.log("input box values--" + $("[name=tags]").val())
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i] == to_remove) {
      values.splice(i, 1);
      return true;
    }
  }
  console.log("after splice--" + values)
  $(this).closest(".label-info").remove()
  $("[name=tags]").val(values)
  console.log("After setting new values--" + $("[name=tags]").val())
})

$('input').on('beforeItemRemove', function(e) {
  e.cancel = true; //set cancel to false..
});
```

```css
.label-info {
  background-color: #17a2b8;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-aAr2Zpq8MZ+YA/D6JtRD3xtrwpEz2IqOS+pWD/7XKIw=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" integrity="sha512-xmGTNt20S0t62wHLmQec2DauG9T+owP9e6VU8GigI0anN7OXLip9i7IwEhelasml2osdxX71XcYm6BQunTQeQg==" crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-OFRAJNoaD8L3Br5lglV7VyLRf0itmoBzWUoM+Sji4/8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.js" integrity="sha512-VvWznBcyBJK71YKEKDMpZ0pCVxjNuKwApp4zLF3ul+CiflQi6aIJR+aZCP/qWsoFBA28avL5T5HA+RE+zrGQYg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" name="tags" class="form-control">
```

I think values which i am getting from input box is not right i.e : not in correct format because when i do `values.length` after splitting it always give value as `1` .

***Edit 1*** :

I tried using `split(',')` it is removing data from array but not printing any `console` result after for loop code and values inside input box doesn't `remove` as well .

**Updated code** :

```
$(document).on("click", ".label-info span[data-role=remove]", function() {
  var to_remove = $(this).closest(".label-info").clone().children().remove().end().text().trim()
  console.log($("[name=tags]").val())
  var values = $("[name=tags]").val().split(',')
  console.log("to remove ---" + to_remove)
  $(this).closest(".label-info").remove()
  console.log("input box values--" + $("[name=tags]").val())
  for (var i = 0; i < $("[name=tags]").val().split(',').length; i++) {
    if (values[i] == to_remove) {
      values.splice(i, 1);
      console.log("i am in")
      return;
    }
  }
  //why thse consoles do not get printed ??
  console.log("after splice--" + values)
  $(this).closest(".label-info").remove()
  $("[name=tags]").val(values)
  console.log("After setting new values--" + $("[name=tags]").val())
})
```

Thank you for helping .

Comment: why do you return in for loop. it exit function. if you want to exit for loop you should use break.  please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [bootstrap-tagsinput source code](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput/blob/master/src/bootstrap-tagsinput.js) at line number 133:

```
// register item in internal array and map
  self.itemsArray.push(item);
```

That means the values you input into the text box are saved into an internal object you see as **tagsinput**. If you change the values of input box without changing the internal object you don't synchronize the text and internal object. This way you don't remove any value. Moreover, the text box is hidden and you see and act with a div.

Instead to get values with:

```
var values = $("[name=tags]").val().split(';')
```

you can use the **itemsArray** property of **tagsinput** data object:

```
var values = $("[name=tags]").data('tagsinput').itemsArray;
```

Now you can work directly with this array.

In order to remove the element you can use [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) instead of for loop:

```
var idx = $(this).closest(".label-info").index();
values.splice(idx, 1);
```

The snippet:

```js
$('input').tagsinput({
    allowDuplicates: true
});
//on click of remove button
$(document).on("click", ".label-info span[data-role=remove]", function () {


    var values = $("[name=tags]").data('tagsinput').itemsArray;
    console.log(values);
    console.log("input box values--" + $("[name=tags]").val());

    // synchronize  internal object and input text
    var idx = $(this).closest(".label-info").index();
    values.splice(idx, 1);
    $("[name=tags]").val(values);

    //remove that spn
    $(this).closest(".label-info").remove();

    console.log("after splice--" + values)
    console.log("After setting new values--" + $("[name=tags]").val())
})

$('input').on('beforeItemRemove', function (e) {
    e.cancel = true; //set cancel to false..
});
```

```css
.label-info {
    background-color: #17a2b8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>

<input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" name="tags" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) . But , can you explain why above code doesn't work ?

Comment: Your code doesn't work because all the data are saved in the dataset "tagsinput" of the input field. You need to use the api or you can act on the dataset

Comment: the reason is not 'tagsinput'. because you write return in 'for loop'. use 'break'.

Comment: Then you should use break. If not in for loop it will remove same values. for example if "inputtag" 's value is "aaa,aaa,aaa,aaa" then after splice value will be "aaa, aaa" .

Comment: ..... **the reason is not 'tagsinput** are you sure? See my comments to your code and mainly what happens if you want to delete the send element instead of the first? With break you remove exactly only the first one.......  You may also read the source code like I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You write return in for loop. It exit function. So some code can not execute.
In the first code when split(";"), string dose not have ";" so it is not splited.
Thus in for loop `values[i] == to_remove` never be true, so return does not execute. Use break to exit for loop. If not all same values will be removed.

```js
$('input').tagsinput({
  allowDuplicates: true
});
//on click of remove button
$(document).on("click", ".label-info span[data-role=remove]", function() {
  //remove that spn
    var to_remove = $(this).closest(".label-info").clone().children().remove().end().text().trim()
    var valuesString =$("[name=tags]").val();
    console.log(valuesString);
    var values = valuesString.split(',');
    console.log("before remove ---" + values)
    console.log("to remove ---" + to_remove)
    $(this).closest(".label-info").remove()
    console.log("input box values--" + $("[name=tags]").val())
    var i = $(this).closest(".label-info").index();
    values.splice(i, 1);
    //for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    //  if (values[i] == to_remove) {
    //     values.splice(i, 1);
    //     break;
       //      return true;
    //  }
    //}
    console.log("after splice--" + values);
    $(this).closest(".label-info").remove();
    $("[name=tags]").val(values);
    $("[name=tags]").data('tagsinput').itemsArray = values;
    console.log("After setting new values--" + $("[name=tags]").val());
 })

$('input').on('beforeItemRemove', function(e) {
  e.cancel = true; //set cancel to false..
});
```

```css
.label-info {
  background-color: #17a2b8;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-aAr2Zpq8MZ+YA/D6JtRD3xtrwpEz2IqOS+pWD/7XKIw=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" integrity="sha512-xmGTNt20S0t62wHLmQec2DauG9T+owP9e6VU8GigI0anN7OXLip9i7IwEhelasml2osdxX71XcYm6BQunTQeQg==" crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-OFRAJNoaD8L3Br5lglV7VyLRf0itmoBzWUoM+Sji4/8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.js" integrity="sha512-VvWznBcyBJK71YKEKDMpZ0pCVxjNuKwApp4zLF3ul+CiflQi6aIJR+aZCP/qWsoFBA28avL5T5HA+RE+zrGQYg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" name="tags" class="form-control">
```

Comment: It is true after remove then update data[tagsinput]. but the reason source code dose not execute is because write return in for loop.

Comment: Please, try to input a then b, remove b, add a, add a and see in the console.......... It is not so hard. For the return I explained you why and what happens: with a break you remove only the first and never the correct one

Comment: Yes. I 'm sorry. I update my code. I mean the source code does not execute because of return in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The values you input are saved in a "tagsinput" object.

You could update both the text and an object every time you change an input as mentioned in some of the replies.

But probably **the best way to do it** would be to ditch the tagsinput plugin you are loading altogether, and replace it with a different one that will handle this for you.

For example, [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/components/chips/#section-new-initial) you can simply use the `editable` option to achieve your goal, and you can use it with pure JavaScript in the latest Bootstrap 5, if you would also prefer to ditch jQuery (which I recommend), but even with jQuery, this one still works.